# Hosting Android Dependencies on GitHub

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android private project (not open source) hosted on GitHub and I need to link it by an Android gradle dependency. I saw a couple of services to dot it like Jitpack.io but it's not free for private repositories. Do you know any free service to do it? Or do you know the way to host my own private project dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have two ways to do it:

1. You can setup your own [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) server, secure it and host
   your dependencies there. You should be able to publish new artifact from the GitHub repo. Nevertheless, it requires some work and machine, where you can host your repositories. I found an article regarding that at: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en.
2. You can generate `*.jar` or `*.aar` file from your library and put it manually to your project into the `lib/` directory. Unfortunately, it's not so convenient like using Artifactory or Maven Central. Nevertheless, you can automate your build in such case via Bash scripts, Gradle and/or Jenkins, so manual work (like copying files) can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) - it is absolutely free and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, I want to add that you can host your Android artifacts on [GitHub packages](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/publishing-and-managing-packages/about-github-packages). and I would recommend this [tutorial](https://rubensousa.com/2020/02/26/github_packages_for_android_projects/) as a start for doing this.